# Buttons are wrapping when rendered HTML/ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table, word-wrap

I am using ASP.NET. I have an html table. One of the table cells (td) has two buttons. Just recently, when it is being rendered it is wrapping the buttons. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: No one can help without seeing your html and css.

Comment: This is a general issue I have seen with multiple projects. I am leaning towards it being something with IE8. I will look for a specific example and post.

Answer (score 1):

The table cell is narrower that the combined width of the buttons.

Try:

`<td nowrap>` on that cell.

Comment: I suspect the width of that cell is hard-coded in one of the rows. If it is, make it wider or delete the width value to allow the nowrap to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
<td style="white-space: nowrap;">
```

Also, make sure you remove any unnecessary white space between the buttons and replace it with `&nbsp;` if you wish to add some spacing.